# Is it possible to solve equation $150000=4050 \frac{(1+r)^{27}-1}{r} $ by hand?

Tags: calculus

Hello is it possible to solve this by hand?

$$
150000=4050 \frac{(1+r)^{27}-1}{r}
$$

I tried but get stuck here:
$$
\frac{1500000}{4050}=(1+r)^{26}-r^{-1}
$$

How can Ii isolate $r$ is just a polynomial of 25 degree and therefore I can solve it?

Comment: You get to $\frac{150000}{4050}=\frac{(1+r)^{27}}r-r^{-1}$ and then what?

Comment: Is $r$ a real number? Is it close to 0?

Comment: @slhulk, my guess is that $r$ is an interest rate.

Comment: @PersonX in that case, $(1+r)^{27}$ can be approximated to $1+27r$

Answer (score 1):

If
$f(r)
=(1+r)^{27}
$,
by the mean value theorem,
$f(r)-f(0)
=rf'(s)
$
where
$0 < s < r$,
so
$\dfrac{f(r)-f(0)}{r}
=f'(s)
=27(1+s)^{26}
$.

So an initial estimate
for the root of
$\dfrac{f(r)-f(0)}{r}
=c
$
would be
$(c/27)^{1/26}-1$.

In your case,
$c = 150000/4050$,
so the estimate would be
$(150000/(27\cdot 4050))^{1/26}=1
=.0122...
$

For comparison,
throwing
$(1+x)^{27}-1 =
x(150000/4050)
$
at Wolfy
returns the positive root of
$x ≈ 0.0233438
$
so the approximation
was off by a factor of about 2.

Answer (score 1):

Recognize the interest rate $r$ is a small quality and expand the equation around $r=0$, i.e.

$$150000=4050(27+\frac12\cdot27\cdot26r +\frac16\cdot27\cdot26\cdot25r^2)$$

Solve the quadratic equation to obtain

$$r= \frac1{450}\left( \sqrt{\frac{55531}{39}}-27\right)\approx 0.0238$$